# How to add csv data to Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, csv, dictionary

I want add every row data from csv into Dictionary in c#

csv is like that :

```
 - id,data 
 - 1,a  
 - 2,b
```

here my code

```
 Dictionary<int, string> m_dicTransactions = new Dictionary<int, string>();
 while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] columns = line.Split(',');

                    m_dicTransactions.Add(columns[0], columns[1]);

                }
```

i want to add id and data to my dictionary, how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the first column to an integer:

```
m_dicTransactions.Add(int.Parse(columns[0]), columns[1]);
```